# How to make sure optional parts of a pattern occure at least once?

Tags: regex, python-re

How to make sure that part of the pattern (keyword in this case) is in the pattern you're looking for, but it can appear in different places. I want to have a match only when it occurs at least once.

**Regex**:

```
 \b(([0-9])(xyz)?([-]([0-9])(xyz)?)?)\b
```

We only want the value if there is a keyword: `xyz`

**Examples**:

```
1. 1xyz-2xyz - it's OK
2. 1-2xyz - it's OK
3. 1xyz - it's OK
4. 1-2 - there should be no match, at least one xyz missing
```

I tried a positive lookahead and lookbehind but this is not working in this case.

Comment: Replace ? with +

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of a conditional construct:

```
\b([0-9])(xyz)?(?:-([0-9])(xyz)?)?\b(?(2)|(?(4)|(?!)))
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/MCJnoY/1). *Details*:

- `\b` - word boundary
- `([0-9])` - Group 1: a digit
- `(xyz)?` - Group 2: an optional `xyz` string
- `(?:-([0-9])(xyz)?)?` - an optional sequence of a `-`, a digit (Group 3), `xyz` optional char sequence
- `\b` - word boundary
- `(?(2)|(?(4)|(?!)))` - a conditional: if Group 2 (first `(xyz)?`) matched, it is fine, return the match, if not, check if Group 4 (second `(xyz)?`) matched, and return the match if yes, else, fail the match.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/bum3lE):

```py
import re
text = "1. 1xyz-2xyz - it's OK\n2. 1-2xyz - it's OK\n3. 1xyz - it's OK\n4. 1-2 - there should be no match"
pattern = r"\b([0-9])(xyz)?(?:-([0-9])(xyz)?)?\b(?(2)|(?(4)|(?!)))"
print( [x.group() for x in re.finditer(pattern, text)] )
```

Output:

```
['1xyz-2xyz', '1-2xyz', '1xyz']
```

Answer (score 2):

Indeed you could use a [lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) in the following way:

```
\b\d(?:xyz|(?=-\dxyz))(?:-\d(?:xyz)?)?\b
```

[See this demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/5HVExr/2) (or using [`^` *start* and `$` *end*](https://regex101.com/r/GgMB0T/1))

---

The first part matches either an `xyz` OR (if there is none) the lookahead ensures that the `xyz` occures in the second *optional* part. The second part is dependent on the previous condition.

Comment: Thank you! That was something i was looking for

Comment: @otbear You're welcome, it's a nice task and you see, many solutions :) Glad you found it helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: `\b(([0-9])?(xyz)+([-]([0-9])+(xyz)+)?)\b`
Replace `?` with `+`
Basically ?: zero or more and in your case you want to match one or more.
Whih is +

Comment: I can't see where that matches `1xyz-2` or `1-2xyz` but it matches e.g. `1xyzxyzxyz` which does not seem to be desired ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/Ar0kVA/1)).

Answer (score 1):

How about something as basic as this

```
(\dxyz-\dxyz|\dxyz-\d|\d-\dxyz|\dxyz)
```

You can add word boundary if needed

```
\b(\dxyz-\dxyz|\dxyz-\d|\d-\dxyz|\dxyz)\b
```

Just an OR